# When can a shopify field connect to a dynamic source?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have added a text input field to my page template, in the hope of linking it to a metafield I have created within the page.

When editing the page template, the input field does not have the icon to link to a dynamic source.

Is there anyway I can make the connection for the page metafield through the template editor?

Answer (score 1):

There are no connections from a Shopify Page to a Metafield for saving. They would be read-only. If you require to save information and write it, you would have to wire up your own App Proxy based save App.